# AngularJS manually bootstrap after receive data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to manually bootstrap AngularJS after receiving data from the server.

bootstrap.js:

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $http = initInjector.get('$http');
var maindata;

function bootstrapAngular() {
    angular.element(document).ready(function() {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    });
}

function getMainData() {
    return maindata;
}

$http
    .get('/data')
    .then(function (response) {
        maindata = response.data;
        bootstrapAngular();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I need to use the `maindata` or `getMaindata()` in the app after it is bootstrapped. Therefore, I cannot have javascript closer `(function(){})();` on `bootstrap.js` file to keep everything private, so that the function & variable is accessible to the other part of the app.

Is it possible to make everything private but still accessible to the other part of the app?

Comment: So the question is that, you want to execute a certain block of code, that will fetch some data from the server,  and use those values in your app, Before anything else happens ??

Comment: @TechMa9iac Yes, that is what I am trying to do. I guess `New Dev`'s answer solve my problem. Or, you have better suggestion how to write it?

Comment: Nope. I guess @NewDev's response fits the requirement (y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could expose `maindata` as an injectable to make it available in your app:

```
$http
    .get('/data')
    .then(function (response) {
        maindata = response.data;

        angular.module("app").value("MainData", maindata);

        bootstrapAngular();
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Then you could inject it in controllers or services:

```
.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, MainData){
   $scope.data = MainData;
});
```